# Storing Javascript Objects in Another Object Dynamically

Tags: javascript, object, methods

Here's what I'm trying to accomplish. I'm creating objects dynamically and I want to add them to a "master container" object. I'm currently using arrays for containers, but sometimes I'd like to access these objects by name instead of by index. Such as:

```
function Scene() {
     this.properties;
}

Scene.prototype.addEntity = function(entity) {
    this.push(entity);
}


var coolNameForObject = { Params };
var Scene1 = new Scene();

Scene1.addEntity(coolNameForObject);
```

I know the .push isn't available, only for arrays, but I'm tired of using indexes all day. I'd like to reference each entity by it's name. e.g:

```
Scene1.coolNameForObject.property
```

But can't think of a good way to do it.

Maybe have something like:

```
coolNameForObject.name = 'coolNameForObject';
Scene1.(coolNameForObject.name) = coolNameForObject;
```

But that syntax comes up bad on Dreamweaver. I've google-ed, but anything that comes up would be more easily solved via an array, and I'm confidant for what I need these objects for, being able to call up objects via property reference on a container object is the way to go.

I could skip the "addEntity()" entirely, and just go

```
Scene1.coolNameForObject = coolNameForObject;
```

But that seems to go against the idea of encapsulation.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Properties of Javascript objects can be added dynamically and named with the square bracket syntax either directly or from a variable:

```
var propName = "foo";
coolNameForObject[propName] = 'coolNameForObject';

coolNameForObject["bar"] = 'coolNameForObject';

Scene.prototype.addEntity = function(name, entity) {
    this[name] = entity;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add property like this and make enumerable: true,this wiil not create problem.
you can acess key easily.

```
 Object.defineProperty(obj, "key", {
  enumerable: true,
  configurable: true,
  writable: true,
 });
```